# Meaning of "Up to 10 Gbps" Bandwidth in EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS ec2 c5.large  instance. According to what I read in here https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/c5/ it says that Network Bandwidth is up to 10 Gbps.

I'm trying to understand that those 10 Gbps are like peak traffic but how can I tell what is the maximum sustained bandwidth that I can put on this machine for say 2 hrs?

From a link shared in below comments https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html I got this that still do not tell what is the actual nominal traffic of these smaller instances:

*Typically, instances with 16 vCPUs or fewer (size 4xlarge and smaller) are documented as having "up to" a specified bandwidth; for example, "up to 10 Gbps". These instances have a baseline bandwidth. To meet additional demand, they can use a network I/O credit mechanism to burst beyond their baseline bandwidth. Instances can use burst bandwidth for a limited time, typically from 5 to 60 minutes, depending on the instance size.
An instance receives the maximum number of network I/O credits at launch. If the instance exhausts its network I/O credits, it returns to its baseline bandwidth. A running instance earns network I/O credits whenever it uses less network bandwidth than its baseline bandwidth. A stopped instance does not earn network I/O credits. Instance burst is on a best effort basis, even when the instance has credits available, as burst bandwidth is a shared resource.*

Comment: Not suited for SO but the answer is it doesn't depend on duration but destination - read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html does that help?

Comment: "Within the Region
Traffic can utilize the full network bandwidth available to the instance." - "To other Regions, an internet gateway, or Direct Connect
Traffic can utilize up to 50% of the network bandwidth available to a current generation instance with a minimum of 32 vCPUs. Bandwidth for a current generation instance with less than 32 vCPUs is limited to 5 Gbps."

Comment: Still not clear what is the nominal traffic. They say "Up to 10GB" but they do not say what is the nominal or the maximum sustained traffic I can do for say 24 continuous hrs.

Comment: the sustained traffic is 10GB dependent on destination - it can either be 50% of bandwidth if outside of network, 5GBps or the max which is 10GB if within region

Answer (score 0):

From investigation done at this Source back in 2017: http://www.deplication.net/2017/08/understanding-ec2-up-to-10-gigabit.html

For r4 instances,

```
Instance    Baseline Gbps 10Gbps Secs
r4.large    0.75          295
r4.xlarge   1.25          589
r4.2xlarge  2.5           1191
r4.4xlarge  5             2390
```

So assuming nothing has changed, per 'large' instance you have roughly 5 minutes of 10Gbps usage.

This is consistent with what we have observed, in that the 'up to 10Gbps' is really a burst functionality and the baseline bandwidth performance is much, much smaller.

If your app is data bandwidth intensive, EC2 is probably not the right answer.

Comment: What would you suggest instead of EC2 for bandwidth-intensive apps?